# retrieve x and y coordinates from array indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I am trying to convert points in an array to an object of lines with start and endpoints.

This is my array:

```js
let icon = [
  [ [], [] ,[] , [], ["a"]],
  [ [],[] ,[] ,[] ,[] ],
  [ [],[] , ["a","b"], ["b","c"],[] ],
  [ [],[] ,[] ,[] ,[] ],
  [ [], ["c","d"],[] , ["d","e"], [] ],
  [ [], [], ["e","f"], ["f","g"], []],
  [ [], [], [], ["g","h"], ["h"]]
];
```

This function is supposed to iterate through the array and populate the empty vertex list object with the x/y coordinates of the points:

```js
let getVertices= function(icon){

  for(let g=0; g<icon.length; g++){
    for (let u=0; u<icon[0].length; u++){

      let foundPoints = icon[g][u];
      
      if(foundPoints.length==1){
        vertexList[foundPoints[0]]=[[u,g]];
        
        if(g==(icon.length-1)){
          console.log("last Point?: " + foundPoints );
        let lastVertix = vertexList[foundPoints[0]];
        console.log("lastVertix: " + lastVertix);
        let lastLetterIndex = vertexLetters.indexOf(foundPoints);
                
        let previousLetter=vertexLetters[(lastLetterIndex-1)];
        console.log("previousLetter: " + previousLetter);
        console.log("last point: " + [vertexList[previousLetter].slice(-1)]);
        vertexList[foundPoints[0]].splice(0, 0, vertexList[previousLetter].slice(-1));
        }
        
        }
      
      if(foundPoints.length==2){
        vertexList[foundPoints[1]]=[[u,g]];
        vertexList[foundPoints[0]].push([u,g]);
        vertexLetters+=foundPoints.at(-1);
      }
  }
}
```

As expected, I get these values for all points:

[image]

But the last vertex doesn't work the same way:

[image]

I am having trouble handling the last point, the issue must lie here:

```js
if (g == icon.length - 1) {
  console.log('last Point?: ' + foundPoints);
  let lastVertix = vertexList[foundPoints[0]];
  console.log('lastVertix: ' + lastVertix);
  let lastLetterIndex = vertexLetters.indexOf(foundPoints);

  let previousLetter = vertexLetters[lastLetterIndex - 1];
  console.log('previousLetter: ' + previousLetter);
  console.log('last point: ' + [vertexList[previousLetter].slice(-1)]);
  vertexList[foundPoints[0]].splice(
    0,
    0,
    vertexList[previousLetter].slice(-1),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is your example for "h" the expected result or the result you are currently getting?

Comment: That's what I am getting. It should behave just as the "a" example, so [[3,6], [4,6]] instead of  [[[3,6]], 4,6].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I try not to completely rewrite a user's code (as it is easier to teach when you are just fixing/modifying a few small things), but I think your code could be significantly reduced and simplified.

There is also some code missing so I'm not entirely sure what some variables are like `vertexList` and `vertexLetters` (*the **vertexList** I assume is what you are returning to show the coordinates*).

That being said, I think using `.forEach()` to loop through your array and simply checking if each of these nested arrays contains your letter via `.includes()` should give you the desired result. Because I'm not sure what `vertexLetters` is or how it factors into your code I do not have that included in my example.

```js
let icon = [
  [ [], [] ,[] , [], ["a"]],
  [ [],[] ,[] ,[] ,[] ],
  [ [],[] , ["a","b"], ["b","c"],[] ],
  [ [],[] ,[] ,[] ,[] ],
  [ [], ["c","d"],[] , ["d","e"], [] ],
  [ [], [], ["e","f"], ["f","g"], []],
  [ [], [], [], ["g","h"], ["h"]]
],
vertexList = []

const _FindCoordinates = letter => {
  vertexList = []
  icon.forEach((a, y) => {
    a.forEach((b, x) => {
      if(icon[y][x].includes(letter)) vertexList = [...vertexList, [x, y]]
    })
  })
  return vertexList
}

console.log(_FindCoordinates("a"))
console.log(_FindCoordinates("h"))
```

#### NOTE

This works for the provided input/example, but depending on how many nested arrays there are, this obviously would not work.